# repetition regex not working

Tags: regex

I want repeated comma `,` or repeated semi colon `;` to become single

both should be independently processed, it should not matter which sequence or jumbling they are apearing, processing of one should not affect processing of other.

so my test input is this and it should become like this (after -> )

```
,, -> ,
,,, -> ,
;; -> ;
;;; -> ;
,; -> ,;
;, -> ;,
,,;; -> ,;
;;,, -> ;,
```

my regex is `([,;]){2,}`
and replacement is `$1` (I am actually using this in foxreplace in firefox, which is based on java, hence that terminology.

but it is not working. it is just putting the first character as the single char output in each line, whatever other chars are there behind that.

`{2,} -> 2` means it should not touch when there is a single occurence of either, no point replacing single occurence with single occurence.
It should match only if either , or ; is coming 2 or more times at one place.

I tried pipe also, to strictly take one of the two, but that also gives the same output.
`([,|;]){2,}`

I tried escaping them also, `"\\` double blackshalsh in foxreplace, which gets converted to single backslash when foxreplace reads that"
but no effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please check out our answers and select the one that works best for you. Also consider upvoting those that turned out helpful.

Comment: If you've solve the problem, then accept an answer. Don't edit the question title so it doesn't read like a question (on the subject of which, your title didn't read much like a question in the first place so you should fix that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternation:

```
(,){2,}|(;){2,}
```

And replace with `$1$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ok2SKR/2).

**Details**:

- `(,){2,}`  - 2 or more commas, but only one is placed into `$1` buffer
- `|` - or
- `(;){2,}`  - 2 or more semi-colons, but only one is placed into `$2` buffer

Comment: This solution will work with any regex engine not supporting inline backreferences (e.g. RE2 in Go (see [regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/AR8FNZ/1))). For all the rest use `([,;])\1+` => `$1` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using a backreference you could use `([,;])\1+` and replace it with `$1`.

This matches repetitions of either `,` or `;`.

Comment: Yes, I actually thought about this when posting my answer :) A rare engine does not support inline backreferences.